# svn commit error: "svn: Server sent unexpected return value (200 OK)"

Tags: svn, ubuntu, tortoisesvn, ubuntu-12.04, subclipse

If I checkout svn-repo to localhost, it's work fine, and I tail apache log file get following output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jul/2014:00:51:49 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 401 658 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:55 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 200 872 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 550 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "MKACTIVITY /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/act/28d01237-7df2-4de9-8714-a3fe413baafc HTTP/1.1" 201 571 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 443 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "CHECKOUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 201 582 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "PROPPATCH /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wbl/28d01237-7df2-4de9-8714-a3fe413baafc/2 HTTP/1.1" 207 473 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "CHECKOUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/ver/2/%E6%96%B0%E5%BB%BA%E6%96%87%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3.txt HTTP/1.1" 201 674 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "PUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wrk/28d01237-7df2-4de9-8714-a3fe413baafc/%E6%96%B0%E5%BB%BA%E6%96%87%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 115 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "MERGE /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 200 558 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
127.0.0.1 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:51:57 +0800] "DELETE /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/act/28d01237-7df2-4de9-8714-a3fe413baafc HTTP/1.1" 204 115 "-" "SVN/1.7.16 neon/0.29.6"
```

If i checkout same svn-repo on my workstation with subclipse 1.8.x, and finish modification and commit them I get following error:

```
RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (200 OK) in response to PUT request for
'/svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wrk/b492bafd-af40-6749-af08-a11a3a899140/some-test.file'
```

This is apache log:

```
192.168.1.77 - - [24/Jul/2014:00:52:33 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 401 662 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:33 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 200 871 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 550 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 550 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:34 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 207 452 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:34 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/bln/3 HTTP/1.1" 207 465 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:34 +0800] "REPORT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 200 779 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - - [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 401 662 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "OPTIONS /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 200 871 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 550 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "MKACTIVITY /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/act/b492bafd-af40-6749-af08-a11a3a899140 HTTP/1.1" 201 585 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "PROPFIND /svn/kmgxgz HTTP/1.1" 207 444 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "CHECKOUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/vcc/default HTTP/1.1" 201 595 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:55 +0800] "PROPPATCH /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wbl/b492bafd-af40-6749-af08-a11a3a899140/3 HTTP/1.1" 207 473 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:56 +0800] "CHECKOUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/ver/3/%E6%96%B0%E5%BB%BA%E6%96%87%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3.txt HTTP/1.1" 201 685 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:56 +0800] "PUT /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wrk/b492bafd-af40-6749-af08-a11a3a899140/%E6%96%B0%E5%BB%BA%E6%96%87%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
192.168.1.77 - diddy [24/Jul/2014:00:52:56 +0800] "DELETE /svn/kmgxgz/!svn/act/b492bafd-af40-6749-af08-a11a3a899140 HTTP/1.1" 204 115 "-" "SVN/1.7.10/javahl neon/0.29.6"
```

My subversion server version is 1.7 under Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I had try TortoriseSVN, SmartSVN, Subclipse many kinds of client, sames error occurs.

Please help!

Comment: Could this be a [firewall or proxy](http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/09/orgtigrissubversionjavahlclientexceptio.html) issue? Can you checkout, but not commit? What about the directory and file permissions on the server? Is the repository _owned_ by the process that's running the Apache httpd server?

Comment: Finally, I figure it out: If I use my domain name in my svn-repo checkout path I can 100% show this error again and again, I think my domain supplier redirect my domain to somewhere(my domain name still in approach process). If I use ip address as checkout path problem is gone.
**see my TortoriseSVN's log**
>Commit
>G:\temp\kmgxgz\1.txt
>G:\temp\kmgxgz\1.txt
>Commit failed (details follow):
>PUT of '/svn/kmgxgz/!svn/wrk/280ce8ce-224a-e14a-9c06->24b973d5788b/1.txt': 200 OK
**response code 200 is strange!**